# Where to start on a basic derivation?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, formal-proofs

I have a problem I've been banging my head against for this derivation, I'm not really sure where to begin:

$P\rightarrow Q, R\rightarrow S \vdash (Q\rightarrow R) \rightarrow (P\rightarrow S) $

I'm not really sure how I can derive down the first two premises out of $\rightarrow$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good thing I saw your earlier posts ...

The key rule is $\rightarrow I$, which (I assume .. I don't know how the rule is exactly defined in the system *you* work with ...) is defined as follows:

$\rightarrow I$: If you have a statement $\psi$ with Scope the set of sentences $\Gamma$ and $\varphi \in \Gamma$, then you can derive $\varphi \rightarrow \psi$ with Scope $\Gamma \setminus \{ \varphi \}$

I also assume that your $A$ (Assumption) rule is defined as follows:

$A$: At any point you can put down any statement $\varphi$ with Scope $\{ \varphi \}$

Applied to your proof:

\begin{array}{llll}
Scope & Step & Derivation & Rule\\
1 & (1) &P & A\\
2 & (2) &P\rightarrow Q& A\\
3 & (3) &Q\rightarrow R & A\\
4 & (4) &R\rightarrow S & A\\
1,2 & (5) &Q & 1,2 \rightarrow E \\
1,2,3 & (6) &R & 3,5 \rightarrow E \\
1,2,3,4 & (7) &S & 4,6 \rightarrow E \\
2,3,4 & (8) &P \rightarrow S & 7 \rightarrow I \\
2,4 & (9) &(Q \rightarrow R) \rightarrow (P \rightarrow S) & 8 \rightarrow I \\
\end{array}

Comment: How can $P$ be an assumption out of this if it's not a premise?

Comment: @Kellen I assume one of the rules in your system is that you can always write down any statement $\varphi$ with scope $\{ \varphi \}$ ... and that would be called the Assumption ($A$) rule.  Of course, not knowing exactly how your rules are defined, I can only assume that you have such an Assumption rule ....  But put it this way: if you didn't have that rule, I think you'd be in serious trouble trying to prove conditionals like you have to do for this one!

Comment: @Kellen Sure!  Did you verify that your $A$ rule does indeed work for any statement and at any time?  And does your $\rightarrow I$ rule work the way I suspected?

Comment: Yeah, Assumptions can be asserted for any statement, And yes, you were correct on the $\rightarrow I$ : )

Comment: @Kellen OK, cool!  These are pretty typical, so I figured, but you never know ... which is why you should typically tell us which logic system you are using, since there are many different ones, so the rules aren't always defined the same.

Comment: Yeah, one of the things I haven't really been clear on is how to state which "rules" are being followed, is there a way to reference some "Standard" ruleset?

Comment: @Kellen Good question ... I've thought for a while to create some different but commonly used sets of rules and have them available in some archive ... but in the absence of that: if you have a web page that would help, otherwise title of book (and hope we have it), and if all else fails describe them in the post.

Comment: @Kellen You're welcome!  BTW: You're doing well on these proofs, I can already tell.

Comment: @Kellen I put the proof in a nicer format .. check out how I did that by hitting the Edit

Comment: I'll use this formatting in the future! No doubt I'll be having plenty more questions : )

Answer (score 0):

Assume the following two statements are true:

$P\rightarrow Q$

and

$R\rightarrow S$

To show $(Q\rightarrow R) \rightarrow (P\rightarrow S)$

assume the premise, $Q\rightarrow R$ is true. Applying the **If-Then Transitive Property**, to

$P\rightarrow Q$ and $Q\rightarrow R$, we get $P\rightarrow R$

Applying the **If-Then Transitive Property** again, to

$P\rightarrow R$ and $R\rightarrow S$, we are forced to conclude that

$P\rightarrow S$ is true.

But this is what we wanted.